# Postman json data needs conversion into a c# class i want to use anything i got back from my API to zillow call

Tags: c#, json, api, postman, jsonreader

So I used postman to retrieve API data from a website named Zillow, the problem I am running into now is I don't know how to use that data that received in a c# class. basically how to call my json, read it, and return into my class. For the record i used post for the API call in postman.

API post - http://www.zillow.com/webservice/ProReviews.htm .....

```
{
    "message": {
        "code": "0",
        "text": "Request successfully processed"
    },
    "response": {
        "results": {
            "screenname": "ahaque",
            "count": "3",
            "proInfo": {
                "name": "Azib Haque",
                "photo": "https://www.zillowstatic.com/static/images/nophoto_h_g.png",
                "profileURL": "http://www.zillow.com/profile/ahaque/",
                "profileLink": "Continue reading",
                "title": "",
                "businessName": "",
                "address": "",
                "phone": "",
                "specialties": "",
                "serviceAreas": [],
                "reviewRequestURL": "http://www.zillow.com/reviews/write/?s=X1-ZU11wnv9uggyj2h_9r65r",
                "reviewCount": "0"
            },
            "proReviews": {
                "review": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All I did right now is copied and pasted my json into visual studio class assuming ill have to do it

Answer (score 2):

You have json data that you need to deserialize, preferably using JSON.Net.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp) [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856846/deserialize-a-json-array-in-c-sharp) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114225/deserialize-json-objects-in-c-sharp) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209565/how-to-deserialize-json-data-c-sharp) [many](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) [times](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/), and there's even a useful [tool that lets you transpile JSON into C# objects](http://json2csharp.com/).